# Win7 Cannot Delete File - File in Use

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I have a file named `Overview-2015.xlsx` and no matter what I do, my computer keeps telling me the file is still in use.

Here's what I have tried:

- COMPUTER RESTART - The only reason I could possibly think that this wouldn't fix the issue is something is opening and running the program upon startup. Although, I have been using this file for the past 3 months and now all of the sudden it does this.
- Process Explorer - I used this program, as suggested by other threads, to try and fish out a program that may be using this file... couldn't find a single thing running an open file with the name `Overview-2015` let alone an excel file

Any idea why this may be happening or a way that I could delete this file?

Comment: Why don't you take a copy of the file, paste it somewhere and remove the old one?

Comment: What happens if you boot into Safe Mode.  Do you get the same error?

Comment: I have a copy of the file, and it is somewhere else, but when I try to delete the original it won't allow me to

Comment: @Ramhound haven't tried booting into safe mode - what would that tell me if it fixes the error? a corrupt file?

Comment: @Adjit - Once you update the question with the relevant information I can draw an accurate conclusion, I won't be sharing my current thoughts, until that happens though.

Answer (score 0):

Try and delete the file in **safe mode**.
In case you don't know how to run it in safe mode:

1. Start the computer and before it starts windows keep hitting <kbd>F8</kbd>
2. When it shows you a menu move the highlighted section to safe mode and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Wait till it boots up